# Running but not sourcing `~/.bash_profile` on file-write

Tags: mojave, bash, iterm

I have an odd but no-longer-reproducible issue with iTerm2 and Bash.

My default iTerm2 profile uses `/usr/local/bin/bash` (Bash 5 installed with Brew) with no arguments. I was trying to determine when and if this profile would source `~/.bash_profile`, so I added some `echo`s. Each time I *wrote* to the file, my open terminal printed the stdout
from running `~/.bash_profile`.

The actual environment in the iTerm2 session *was not* modified (e.g. new variable definitions added to `.bash_profile` were not visible).

This behavior disappeared when I added the `-l` argument (without which Bash should not actually be using `.bash_profile`), and *did not recur* when I removed the argument.

I was unable to reproduce the behavior in `Terminal` or with the system default Bash.

Has anyone seen this behavior? Why does it happen?

---

Edit: as requested, here is the content of `.bash_profile`, *without* the `echo` statements and variable assignments I added to debug the issue:

```
if [ -e /Users/kstrand/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh ]; then . /Users/kstrand/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh; fi # added by Nix installer
if [[ -s ~/.bashrc ]]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

And `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"

test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash"
```

My `.bashrc` setup is fairly complicated but can be found [here](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/public-config) (all files named `bash*` are symlinked as hidden files in the home dir, i.e. `~/.bashrc -> public-config/bashrc`).

Comment: Please add the content of the related files (.bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile) to the question.

Comment: Also make sure that you can reproduce the problem you are describing here, it may be difficult to diagnose otherwise.

Comment: @nohillside As I said in the question, I wasn't able to reproduce it after it stopped happening. I can try a bit more this week and update the question if I succeed.

Comment: @nohillside I don't believe my rc-files affected the behavior, but I've posted them as requested.